# Data com valor zerado Doctrine

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine

Boa tarde,

Estou usando o ***doctrine*** em meu projeto laravel para controlar o banco.
Estou tentando inserir uma data mas ele não retorna nenhum valor. Se eu uso o **$_POST** eu consigo ver o valor.

Função salvar:

```
public function salvar(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
        {
            $FinContaspagar = new FinContaspagar(
                $request->get('grupo'),
                $request->get('estabelecimento'),
                $request->get('terceiro'),
                $request->get('codigo'),
                $request->get('dtemissao'),
                $request->get('dtvencimento'),
                $_POST['dtemissao'],
                $_POST['dtvencimento']
            );
            echo dd($FinContaspagar);
        }
```

Entity:

```
private $dtemissao;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="dtvencimento", type="date", nullable=false)
 */
private $dtvencimento;

/**
 * @ORM\param $grupo
 * @ORM\param $estabelecimento
 * @ORM\param $terceiro
 * @ORM\param $codigo
 * @ORM\param $dtemissao
 * @ORM\param $dtvencimento
 */

public function __construct($grupo, $estabelecimento, $terceiro, $codigo, $dtemissao, $dtvencimento)
{
    $this->grupo = $grupo;
    $this->estabelecimento = $estabelecimento;
    $this->terceiro = $terceiro;
    $this->codigo = $codigo;
    $this->dtEmissao = $dtemissao;
    $this->dtVencimento = $dtvencimento;
}
```

Form:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'contas/salvar']) !!}

{!! Form::label('grupo','Grupo') !!}
{!! Form::input('number','grupo', null, ['class' => 'form-control','autofocus','placeholder'=>'Grupo']) !!}<br />

{!! Form::label('estabelecimento','Estabelecimento') !!}
{!! Form::input('number','estabelecimento', null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Estabelecimento']) !!}<br />

{!! Form::label('terceiro','Terceiro') !!}
{!! Form::input('number','terceiro', null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Terceiro']) !!}<br />

{!! Form::label('codigo','Codigo') !!}
{!! Form::input('number','codigo', null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Codigo']) !!}<br />

{!! Form::label('dtemissao','Data de Emissão') !!}
{!! Form::input('date','dtemissao', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}<br />

{!! Form::label('dtvencimento','Data de Vencimento') !!}
{!! Form::input('date','dtvencimento', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}<br />

{!! Form::submit('Salvar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Retorno na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Obrigado

Comment: `$request->all()` retorna o que? pode postar isso?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic encontrei o erro, no meu **__construct** eu passei a variável com letra maiúscula... Já resolvi meu amigo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o erro, escrevi o nome da variável dentro do **__construct** com letra maiúscula.